# Unable to pass multiple parameters

Tags: vba, subroutine

I have a subroutine that looks like this. It has two parameters.

```
Sub Advance(ByRef listR() As String, rCount)
    ...code
End Sub
```

When I try to call this:

```
Advance listR:=theList, theCount
```

It gives me a compile error:

> Expected: named parameter

Why is this? It works fine like...

```
Sub Advance(rCount)
    ...code
End Sub
```

And called via:

```
Advance theCount
```

Or also works with just the array parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that you can call your sub any of the following ways, but you can't name the first parameter and not name the second one:

```
Advance listR:=theList, rCount:=theCount
Advance rCount:=theCount, listR:=theList
Advance theList, rCount:=theCount
Advance theList, theCount

Call Advance(listR:=theList, rCount:=theCount)
Call Advance(rCount:=theCount, listR:=theList)
Call Advance(theList, rCount:=theCount)
Call Advance(theList, theCount)
```

Answer (score 2):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/51wfzyw0.aspx):

> When you supply arguments by a mixture of position and name, the positional arguments must 
>   all come first. Once you supply an argument by name, the remaining arguments must all be by 
>   name.